# Performing linear regressions using columns of two matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, lm

I have two large matrices with the same dimensions e.g.:

```
#dummy matrices
A <- matrix(c(1:3288),nrow=12) 
B <- matrix(c(3289:6576),nrow=12)
```

For each column I would like to run a linear regression between the two matrices (A and B) and if possible I would like to get the output of the lm into a data frame e.g. for each column's regression I want to know lm the r^2, the slope, the intercept etc.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Start with `lm_list <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(A)), function(i) lm(A[, i] ~ B[, i]))` and then do `coef_list <- lapply(lm_list, coef)` and `smry_list <- lapply(lm_list, summary)`. From the latter it's easy to get `r²`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you'll fit the regression between any two combination of columns this could be a solution. Keep in mind that depending on what you'll finally want in the resulting data.frame the code will change.

```
A <- matrix(c(1:3288),nrow=12) 
B <- matrix(c(3289:6576),nrow=12)


library(broom)
library(dplyr)

results <- NULL

for (i in 1:ncol(A)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(B)){
    model_<-lm(A[,i]~B[,j])

    results<-bind_rows(results,
                       bind_cols(columnx = i, 
                                 columny = j,
                                 glance(model_),
                                 intercept=model_$coefficients[1],
                                 slope=model_$coefficients[2]
                       )
    )
  }
}
```

If you only need pairwise regression in the form of column 1 in A is going to be fitted with column 1 in B, 2 with 2 and so on, a more elegant solution could be written using map from the purr package. Hope this helps.

Edit: only fitting 1 in A with 1 in B a so forth

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)


A<-data.frame(A)
B<-data.frame(B)

results <- map2_df(.x = A,
     .y = B, ~ {

       model_<-lm(.y ~ .x)
       bind_cols(glance(model_),
                 intercept=model_$coefficients[1],
                 slope=model_$coefficients[2]
       )
     })
```

Here is the purrr [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/map2). It is very clear explaining how map2_df works. It basically loops over two lists at the same time executing one function and returning a data.frame.

Comment: Hi @Phill - I do only need the pairwise regression of column 1 A to column B and 2 with 2 actually etc...so that would be really great! - thank you for your quick response!

Comment: I just edited the answer to include that scenario. Keep in mind that the number of  columns in both matrix has to be the same. if number of columns is not as consistent between matrix maybe the "for" approach could be more fexible but  much less efficient :)

Comment: Ahhh one problem with my data set, the Na's .... is there a way to add an na.omit=T aspect to this? perhaps within model_<-lm(.y ~ .x, na.omit=T) - Thanks.

Comment: In that case the argument in lm that let you handle NA is na.action, you can review it here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.2/topics/lm and here https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-does-r-handle-missing-values/. Based on your comment you may want to use na.action=na.omit whithin the lm call

Comment: I think NAs makes my plan a lot more complicated. My data is a time series, each column in my matrices = a day, each row a min of that day (dim = 1440,2550).... needless to say there is a lot of data each day, but in my two variables quite a few of the days will have NAs and using the omit and exclude i get:  Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases .... there is this discussion: stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/how-does-r-handle-missing-values-in-lm, I need to do more reading to understand it. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: you're welcome :) have you considered some kind of inputation? or aggregating the observation to weekly data? Additionally you could use complete.cases before running any estimation to review how big the NA problem is

Comment: I am actually really interested in the daily variation - it is possible that i could aggregate by the hour (maybe my best option), on the minute scale each day will likely have some NA's - thus I would need to be able to to only omit the NA's on the specific columns when running each individual lm, that is way beyond my abilities

Comment: Taka a look at the xts package https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/r-xts-cheat-sheet I think it'll help you in your quest :)